# loop a matrix through disorder columns indices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A which has 100 rows and 5 columns, I would like to iterate the matrix with disorder indices of columns and save them in each iteration, column indices [2;5;3;4;1].
1st iteration: get all the rows of A with column 2 then do some processes.
2nd iteration : get all the rows of A with columns 2 and 5.
.....
last iteration: get all the rows and columns of A.
Anyone helps me to implement it on Matlab environment please.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

Define the column indices as `cols = [2 5 3 4 1];` and iterate through each submatrix of `A` like `subA = A(:,cols(1:i))`.

```
A = rand(100,5);
cols = [2 5 3 4 1];
for i = 1:length(cols)
    subA = A(:,cols(1:i));
    % do calculations on subA ..
end
```